# ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list issue in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

could someone pls try help me to fix the issue? I already did a lot of debugging and troubleshooting but hit the wall. I won't copy the whole script but rather the function that fails:

```
def deleteOperation(lname1, sKeys, lname2):
    delMaster = copy.deepcopy(lname2)
    for k, v in lname1:
        if k not in sKeys:
            delMaster.remove((k, v))
    return delMaster
```

Here are the values from parameter list:

```
lname1 = [(1, 'one'), (3, 'three'), (5, 'five'), (7, 'seven')]
sKeys = [1, 2, 3]
lname2 = [(1, 'one'), (3, 'third'), (5, 'five'), (7, 'seven')]
```

This function should delete elements `(5,'five')` and `(7,'seven')` from the list but when I execute it I've got the error:

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Actually all values I've got by using pyodbc and connecting to MS SQL database and reading two tables and having those values in lname1 and lname2.

Interesting enough that if I use interactive Python shell and manually assign values exactly as I printed above and run exactly the same commands as my function does it works without error.
Any clue why it happened in my script?
Appreciate any input.

P.S. If I put a breakpoint on line 4 I see all correct values but it looks that inside list.remove() it failed

Comment: I just ran your code, and it returns `[(1, 'one'), (3, 'third')]` as expected.

Comment: Is is possible that lname2 and lname1 have different contents ?

Comment: It would be more usual in Python to just build a new copy that contains only the desired keys, rather than build a complete deep copy and then remove undesired keys.  Is there a reason you are doing it this way?

Comment: Post your actual code please. Also, I think it would be much easier to just return a new dictionary `{key: lname2[key] for key in lname1}`.

Comment: lname1 and lname2 do have different content i.e. (3,'tree') and (3,'third') and it should be that way because in a previous operation I updated lname1 with a new value 'third'

Comment: @susja: But do they have identical content for the `5` and `7` pairs? I'm willing to bet they do when you test it in the interactive shell, but don't in your real program, and that's why you're having a problem.

Comment: I don't think the question is clear here. Your question attempts to return key-value pairs from `lname2`. But you've accepted two different answers that completely ignore `lname2` and instead return key-value pairs from `lname1` (which is a simpler problem). Which one are you actually trying to do?

Comment: at some point, lname1 and lname2 were define as equal. This edition makes quite unclear which is for what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and just use a list comprehension. Then you don't have to worry about the fact that `filter` doesn't return a `list` in Python3. This works equally well in Python2 or Python3

```
>>> lname1 = [(1, 'one'), (3, 'three'), (5, 'five'), (7, 'seven')]
>>> sKeys = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [(x, y) for x, y in lname1 if x in sKeys]
[(1, 'one'), (3, 'three')]
```

Comment: I don't think this is answering the question. Notice that the OP's original code returns the keys and values from *`lname2`*, not *`lname1`*. In particular, you're returning `(3, 'three')` instead of `(3, 'third')`.

Comment: @abarnert, I think this whole question is unanswerable at the moment. We don't really know what is supposed to happen when `k` matches and `v` doesn't. susja hasn't even considered that case yet. I left this here because it's better than the answer using `filter`

Comment: I tried to explain that in my answer, and at first the OP agreed with my guess as to what he meant… but then he accepted a different answer that assumed that `lname2` was actually supposed to be ignored completely, which means… yeah, I don't think he actually knows what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler procedure :

```
>>> lname1=[(1,'one'),(3,'three'),(5,'five'),(7,'seven')]
>>> sKeys=[1,2,3]
>>> filter(lambda (x,y) : x in sKeys, lname1)
[(1, 'one'), (3, 'three')]
```

Create a new array containing only the items from `lname1` that have a first element in `sKeys`.

Comment: It worked fine now in my program. Could you please just explain how lambda works in your case. It looks that I'm all set now. Just would like to understand the flow

Comment: @susja: lambda just defines a function. `lambda (x, y): x in sKeys` defines the exact same function as `def fn(x, y): return x in sKeys`. Although really, you don't need a function here at all; you can just use a comprehension, like `[x for x, y in lname1 if x in sKeys]`.

Comment: As a side note, this syntax is deprecated (and won't work in 3.x); you need parens around the entire lambda, and you _shouldn't_ have parens around the argument list.

Comment: @abarnert, In Python3, you would also need to use `list(filter(...))`

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm just amazed by the number of positive responses.

Comment: Anyway finally I decided to go with gnibbler answer since it looks most clear to me and short.

Comment: After re-reading the question, this one has the same problem as gnibbler's answer—unless the question is completely wrong, this returns the wrong values, because it completely ignores `lname2` (instead of returning pairs from `lname2`).

Comment: @abarnert : the parenthesis around the argument here are to indicate that there is only one parameter that is a tuple.

Comment: @njzk2: Which is exactly what was made illegal in [PEP 3113](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/). The PEP explains why, but the short version is: Python doesn't do pattern matching in general, and this very limited subset of pattern matching that Python 2 did causes more problems than it solves, so Python 3 doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `lname1` is a list of `(k, v)` pairs, `lname2` is a list of `(k, w)`, and you're trying to remove a `(k, v)` pair from a copy of `lname2`. That doesn't make any sense.

With the values you happen to have, `v` and `w` are identical for all of the `k` values that aren't in `sKeys`, so you get away with it. But that's manifestly not true in general—as implied by the `(3, 'third')` in your example, and as you explicitly said in a comment.

So, if you're trying to remove all `(k, w)` pairs from `lname2` where some `(k, v)` is in `lname1`, but `k` is not in `sKeys`, you're doing it wrong; you need an extra search to find the right `w`:

```
def deleteOperation(lname1, sKeys, lname2):
    delMaster = copy.deepcopy(lname2)
    for k, v in lname1:
        if k not in sKeys:
            for k2, w in lname2:
                if k2 == k:
                    delMaster.remove((k, w))
    return delMaster
```

---

Or, reorganize things to walk `lname2` first instead.

---

Or, most simply, convert these things into dicts and sets in the first place so the whole operation becomes trivial:

```
def deleteOperation(lname1, sKeys, lname2):
    for k in lname1:
        if k not in sKeys:
            del lname2[k]
    return lname2
```

---

If you don't actually need to mutate `lname2`, but just want to return values from `lname2` chosen by using `lname1`, you can make this simpler. Then it would just be:

```
def deleteOperation(lname1, sKeys, lname2):
    d2 = dict(lname2)
    return [(k, d2[k]) for k, v in lname1 if k in sKeys]
```

And again, it would be even simpler if you used the right data structures in the first place:

```
def deleteOperation(lname1, sKeys, lname2):
    return {k: lname2[k] for k in sKeys & lname1.keys()}
```

Comment: abarnert - thanks a lot. You answer is nice but I preferred to use more simple solution using lambda. Appreciate it.

Comment: @susja: If you used dicts and sets in the first place, and you don't need to mutate things, the dict comprehension in Blender's comment is far simpler than _either_ answer.

Answer (score 0):

To better diagnose your better, you could handle the exception like this

```
def deleteOperation(lname1, sKeys, lname2):
    delMaster = copy.deepcopy(lname2)
    for k, v in lname1:
        if k not in sKeys:
            try:
                delMaster.remove((k, v))
            except ValueError:
                print("{} not found in {}".format((k,v), delMaster))
    return delMaster
```

It's an unusual approach to copy the list and then delete from it. Usually it's more efficient and safer to copy the items you *do* want in to a new datastructure. Is there a particular reason you are doing it this way?